# break line after a full stop in jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to break the paragraph after a full stop. I am using jsoup to capture the data from a website. How do i break the line after a sentence ends? Here is my codes that i have tried so far.

```
try {
System.out.println("k");
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/gene/TSG101 ").get();
org.jsoup.select.Elements els = doc.select("p");



StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element el : els) {
sb.append(System.getProperty(".\n"));
System.out.println(el.text());

sb.append(el.text());}

System.out.println(sb.toString());

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Break line after a full stop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344952/break-line-after-a-full-stop)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
sb.append(el.text().append('\n'));
```

Comment: it is not working. Did you try the codes? When i am printing it.The text is display on one line. But i want to seperate it after a sentence ends.

Comment: Try `System.getProperty("line.separator")` instead of `sb.append(System.getProperty(".\n"));`