# Break line after a full stop

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using jsoup to extract content from a webpage. But i want to break the paragraph and display the content on a line by line. This code does not display line by line.Codes that i have tried:

```
try {
System.out.println("k");
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/gene/TSG101 ").get();
org.jsoup.select.Elements els = doc.select("p");



 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.append(System.getProperty(".\r\n"));
 for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element el : els) {

 System.out.println(el.text());

 sb.append(el.text());
 }

 System.out.println(sb.toString());

 }
```

Comment: i've never used jsoup but if this "el" string is a line of web content, then you can control if there is a <br> or <p> element, then you can parse it.

Comment: Perhaps there should be a line break which will break each line after there is a period.

Comment: what do you get from "el.text" variable?

Comment: what do you get when you print sb.toString()

Comment: It prints all the contents which is in tag <p> on the web page. But I want to display the content like a line by line. That is after a period it changes the line and display the text on another line.

Comment: @AloneInTheDark It extract the content from the webpage like text.

Answer (score 1):

If you want breaks after each line, just write something like that:

```
for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element el : els) {
if(el.text().replace(".",".\n");
    sb.append(el.text());

}
```

Comment: For this code I am getting this output:                                The official name of this gene is “tumor susceptibility 101.<br>”TSG101 is the gene's official symbol.<br>

Answer (score 0):

You print the content paragraph by paragraph in the loop, but you're appending the paragraphs to the `StringBuilder` without appending line breaks.

```
final String lineBreak = System.getProperty("line.separator");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element el : els) {
    sb.append(el.text());
    sb.append(lineBreak);
}

 System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: It is printing the text but the sentence is not being break after a period.why is that so?

Comment: If you can show us a few outputs of "el.text()", i can explain you why.

Comment: The text is too long so i will show the first lines that is being output.

Comment: TSG101 is the gene's official symbol. The TSG101 gene is also known by other names, listed below.
Read more about gene names and symbols on the About page.
The protein encoded by this gene belongs to a group of apparently inactive homologs of ubiquitin-conjugating enzymes. The gene product contains a coiled-coil domain that interacts with stathmin, a cytosolic phosphoprotein implicated in tumorigenesis.

Comment: @AloneInTheDark As you see the text that it is printing. After each period it should have been on a single line for example TSG101 is the gene's official symbol.Then line breaks then on next line The TSG101 gene is also known by other names, listed below.

Comment: Then you have to split the text at `.` and append a line break after each split array element.

Comment: just edit your question and put 2-3 lines from your "el.text()" output. That won't hurt us.

Answer (score 0):

if `sb` or `el` contains the entire text, you could replace each instance of `.` with `.\n` as below

```
String el = "your text. your text next line. third line.";
String[] l = el.split("\\.");
for (String string : l) {
    System.out.println(string+ ".");
}
```

Comment: does contain the string you want to split, the contents of `<p>`?